# Is there a way to make a machine learning script that would create a language from another language?

Tags: machine-learning

For example, I would like to have it create a language that is based on French, it would make the language along with the corresponding English translation. This is really out of my area of expertise so any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your description is not clear, please add some detailed examples

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are talkin about unsipervised translation, I think this [repo](https://github.com/omarfoq/unsupervised_translator) matches with what you are tying to do.